# Python Pandas data adding columns instead of rows and maintaining columns order per original dataset

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a small dataset that I need to reshape the layout by displaying all related records (related by ID) on the same row. The order of the columns changes once I Pivot the data in pandas as showing in the second image below. How can I maintain the order of the columns to that of the original dataset please?

original dataset

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
'ID':[33,33,3,21,21,3,33],
'FirstName':['Joseph','Mary','Abram','Peter','John','Daniel','Cat'],
'LastName':['JosephL','MaryL','AbramL','PeterL','JohnL','DanielL','CatL'],
'CAR':['BMW','MB','Opel','Fiat','VW','','Ford'],
'Salary':[1250,3254,2599,4566,7855,9999,7500]
})
```

Outcome

[image]

Pivoting the data to stack related records as new columns instead of new rows.

```
g = df.groupby(['ID']).cumcount().add(1) 
df = df.set_index(['ID',g]).unstack(fill_value=0).sort_index(axis=1,level=1)
df.columns=["{}{}".format(a,b) for a,b in df.columns]
df = df.reset_index()
df
```

The order is not right, it should be FirstName, LastName, Salary, Car, FirstName, LastName, Salary, Car, FirstName, LastName, Salary, Car...etc

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use `pivot_table` after defining a custom column index:

```
vals = ['FirstName', 'LastName', 'CAR', 'Salary']
idx = df.groupby('ID').cumcount().add(1).astype(str)
out = (df.pivot_table(index='ID', columns=idx, values=vals, aggfunc='first', fill_value=0)
         .sort_index(level=1, axis=1).reset_index())
out.columns = out.columns.to_flat_index().map(''.join)
print(out)

# Output
   ID  CAR1 FirstName1 LastName1  Salary1 CAR2 FirstName2 LastName2  Salary2  CAR3 FirstName3 LastName3  Salary3
0   3  Opel      Abram    AbramL   2599.0          Daniel   DanielL   9999.0   NaN        NaN       NaN      NaN
1  21  Fiat      Peter    PeterL   4566.0   VW       John     JohnL   7855.0   NaN        NaN       NaN      NaN
2  33   BMW     Joseph   JosephL   1250.0   MB       Mary     MaryL   3254.0  Ford        Cat      CatL   7500.0
```

Comment: Thank you @Corralien for your reply, but that didn't change the order of the columns, I am looking for a specific column order please?